# How can I implement session handling in Blazor?

Tags: session, blazor, session-variables, session-state

In all web technologies like PHP or ASP.NET there is the concept of sessions.
Blazor doesn't seem to have that at all.
As soon as I switch to a new page, I lose all data.
I don't understand why there isn't a simple session concept like in other web technologies.

I tried to set up a session handling myself.
On the one hand with static variables on the other hand with various complicated and heavyweight tutorials from the internet.

Comment: Look up Dependency Injection and scoped services.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should know is that blazor server side is based on SignalR so
there is Circuit for each user connection to server, when crash or something occur in app this Circuit will close,

you need a session like app in blazor server, first thing you need to specify clients with something like "Session-ID" for each user

**you can use Browser "Coockie" or "LocalStorage" and generate an ID and store in client side**

and in server side create Dictionary base values for this id to hold user data
best is ***MemoryCache***.
you can also **SetSlidingExpiration** and set timeout of session in MemoryCache

[read more about MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0)